# What kind of changes does Chrome pick up using Live Edit?

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, webstorm

The live edit page at http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7007 says "Since version 0.5 LiveEdit works as part of JavaScript debug session only.". That works fine for me.

John Lindquist's live edit demo at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCVwdvufTds (which is really awesome !) shows Chrome picking up DOM changes without a reload as well. Still a static page, but definitely more than just Javascript debugging.

Not everybody gets away with one static file on the server, and pages use dynamically loaded code as well (e.g. partials in AngularJS).

What kind of changes does Chrome pick up without hitting the reload button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveEdit synchronizes html,css and javascrit using hotswap — browser tab is not reloaded. But PHP and layout files (smarty, twig)  can obly be synchronized using reload. Note also that not each and every change in javascript code results in immediate page update: new code is loaded to the browser instantly, but the results of the change will be visible only when you do something to trigger this new code. For example if you change the onClick handler and write new text in alert, you will see the new text after the click without reloading the page.
But if the JS code is executed only on page load (and not on certain event), you have to manually reload the page to see the results - live edit doesn't force new code execution

And one more note: live editing for AngularJS doesn't currently work as expected - see [WEB-7734](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7734) and related tickets

Comment: When connected, does intellij have a clue which resources make up the page ? Does intellij leverage path<->resource name mapping, or how does intellij figure out which changes need to propagate to chrome ? I mean assume I have a project directory /foo in intellij mapped to http://localhost/bar, and I update /foo/sample/test.css which is referenced as /bar/sample/test.css from the page. That should be working, right ?

Comment: right. But you need to make sure that the mappings are available to WebStorm - it needs to know what web URL the certain local file is mapped to. This is what 'remote URL' field in javaScript Debug run configuration is used for

Comment: Just tried it again with Javascript and found Chrome does not pick up changes I make in Intellij when http is used. Breakpoints, and stack works as expected. What a pity. :(

Comment: works fine for me. Please file a bug to youtrack providing the details (sample project is welcome) or create a support ticket

Answer (score 0):

BTW here you could find in description pseudo-live-edit code (useful for windows user with AHK).
please give it a like ;)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0QFoAkKEwM